# Change the value of an array changes original array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

The following code causes both elements from id `0` to be set to `-`, even though I want only one to be set to `-1`. Am I just creating a reference to the labelArray, or is something else?

```
labelArray.sort(compare);
valueArray = labelArray;
valueArray[0] = '-1';
labelArray[0] = '-';
```

All help is appreciated.

UPDATE (2019): It's been several years since I first did this post, and ES6 is used pretty much universally. So, I wanted to come back and add that, instead of using the `slice()` method recommended in the accepted answer, you can instead use [array destructing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) in the following to make a copy:

```
valueArray = [...labelArray];
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes. Both `valueArray` and `labelArray` reference the same underlying array.** To make a copy, use [slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
valueArray = labelArray.slice(0);
```

NOTE: Slice() only copies 1 level deep, which works fine for primitive arrays. If the array contains complex objects, use something like jQuery's [clone()](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), credit @Jonathan.

Comment: @deth4uall Yes, variables, object properties, and array slots in JS all _reference_ values, they do not _contain_ them.

Comment: @deth4uall Not _because_, per se, but by convention. In many OO languages objects are distinct from their references, unlike primitives, probably because the compiler would have to infer too much to perform a deep-copy.

Comment: Thanks guys, if I had known for certain it was an object I would never had needed to ask. Your help has been quite enlightening.

Answer (score 2):

> Am I just creating a reference to the labelArray […] ?

Yes, exactly. `valueArray` and `labelArray` still identify the same object, which hasn't been copied.

Answer (score 1):

`valueArray` is just a reference to `labelArray`.

What you want to do is clone the array.  You can do this using jQuery.clone() or a similar cloning function.

Comment: The project is not using jQuery so that is not on table right now. I am probably going to end up moving to jQuery anyways.