# Bootstrap tags input binding issue

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I have a situation where I need to remember what the value of a tagsinput field was before changes were made.  However, some of the information is dynamically binded so when the input changes so does the value of my variable that references it.

```
var topics = $("#topics").tagsinput('items');
$('#topics').tagsinput('add', 'A');
$('#topics').tagsinput('add', 'B');

var LISA = topics;
alert('Lisa is: ' + JSON.stringify(LISA));
$('#topics').tagsinput('add', 'newone');
alert('Lisa is: ' + JSON.stringify(LISA));
```

So what I'd like is the variable `Lisa` to *not* have `newone` added to it.

But with the bootstrap tags input jQuery plugin the variable changes dynamically with the values.  Anyone know how to turn off this binding so I can recall what the value of the field was *before* new information is added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The Problem

This has nothing to do with bootstrap-tags per se. It's a byproduct of the way JavaScript creates variables.  Consider, for example, the following JavaScript:

```
var array = ["A", "B"];
var copy = array; 

array.push("C");
copy.push("D");

console.log(array);
console.log(copy);
```

Both `array` and `copy` will equal `["A", "B", "C", "D"]`

The object `copy` just contains a reference back to `array` so they both resolve to the same object.  Updating one updates both. See also: [value of an array changes original array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9024709/1366033).

### The Solution

What you want to do instead is [clone an object in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/122102/1366033), like this:

```
var LISA = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(topics));
```

Now `LISA`  will not be updated when `topics` changes.

#### [Demo in fiddle (open up the console)](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/fV65e/)

Comment: Amazing!  Thank you!  Just tested it and it works like a charm.